# Ubuntu 12.04.3 for VMware Player

Tags: 12.04, vmware

I have VMware Player running in Windows 7 and I need the Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS Precise Pangolin  for a project.
Could anyone help me where can I download the Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS to run it in VMware Player, please?

Comment: Firstly, why do you need 12.04? Why not 14.04 or 16.04? Secondly, have you tried just downloading the ISO and installing it? This is stuff you can Google.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.3 reached its end-of-life and isn't supported any longer (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Current). Therefore it's off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need 12.04.3, you can find the ISO file in the [old releases archive for Precise](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/) . The ISO file is suitable for installation in VMware Player.